# Zend Session do not get destroyed on window close

Tags: zend-framework

My Zend session (I am using Zend_Session_Namespace) do not get destroyed on window close. I thought that was the default behavior and I would really like it to. Any idea?

Comment: Presumably you're not using `Zend_Session::rememberMe()`?  Have you tried calling `Zend_Session::forgetMe()` before calling `Zend_Session::start()`?

Comment: there is no remember me anywhere, tried with forget me, doesnt work, it is still persisting...

Comment: What browser are you using?  Are you closing the whole browser or just the tab?

Comment: @ChrisAnstey chrome and firefox...tried with both...i mean closing browser and tab...

Answer (score 2):

Check and delete any code like this in your application.ini file

```
remember_me_seconds = 864000
```

In login controller use the the following piece of code, then it should work fine.

```
$remember=$form->getValue("remember")
if ($remember=="yes") {
$seconds=60 * 60 * 24 * 30; (remember for 30 days)
Zend_Session::RememberMe($seconds);
}
else {
Zend_Session::ForgetMe();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if this helps but here goes.

There are two ways to 'destroy' a session.

1. On the client side - the cookie
2. On the server side - the session namespace

The session on the browser is not really destroyed when the browser window is closed. What happens is that the browser will delete the cookie. When the browser goes to your site again it doesn't have a cookie anymore and has to get a new session.

If you set the 'life' of a session to be really short, then the session will be deleted on the server really quickly. Even if a browser with a cookie comes along, if there is no matching session on the server then it will end up getting a new session.

You have to find a way to set the cookie parameter that tells the browser to delete it on window close. I'm not sure what portion the rememberMe() function acts on,whether it's the cookie or the session on the server.

If you set this parameter, the browser will delete the cookie on window close and you'll have 'deleted' the session on the browser side.